# How to get form return without AJAX using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal form that sometimes return a file or redirects the user to another page. It's a report form where they can see results in PDF, chart (page), Excel or HTML (page).

I don't have and I can't have a AJAX submission. I have only the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    $('.loading').fadeIn();
    return;
});
</script>

<form id="myForm" action="script.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
</form>
```

This is a generic case to exemplify my actual code.
What I want is to get the return of the form (in my case just the true return when it's a file download) to either remove the loading or place an error message.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe and post your form to it. The iframe wil upload the file and can send a message back when it is done.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myForm').submit(function(){
            $('.loading').fadeIn();
        });
    });

    function onReturn(success){
        if(success == "true"){
            $('.loading').fadeOut();
            // Show the PDF?
        } else {
            $('.loading').html('something went wrong!');
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="myForm" target="controller" method="post" action="script.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
    <div class="loading" style="display:none">Loading...</div>
</form>
```

and in your script.php something like:

```
<?php
    $success = isset($_POST['first_name']) && $_POST['first_name'] == "Grigolon" ? "true" : "false";
    echo "<script>window.top.onReturn('$success');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: `iFrames` would only be useful for an ajax submission. Per the OP's question: _"I don't have and I can't have a AJAX submission."_

Comment: You don't need AJAX to upload a file using an Iframe.

Comment: You don't have to have an ajax submission but what would be the purpose of using the iframe then? If you're not ajaxing, then a regular form post and page reload would do the trick just the same. No need to use an iframe.

Comment: It's not a file upload, it's download.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use an AJAX solution? Anyways. You can target your submission to a hidden iframe, which in turn calls a JS function. Take a look at this:

```
<script>
function onReturn(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    $('.loading').fadeIn();
    return;
});
</script>

<!-- HTML markup -->
<iframe name="uTarget" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form id="myForm" action="script.php" target="uTarget">
 [...]
</form>
```

And then in the script.php in the end, you do something like:

```
<?php
echo "<script>window.top.onReturn('This is being sent from the script!');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Could be a solution. Is there native way using eventListener or anything similar?

Comment: Not AFAIK. Either you serialize the form-data and send it through $.ajax(). Or you target the request to an hidden iframe. Welcome to the beautiful world of problem solving.